# how can cookies track users despite same origin policy?

Tags: tracking, privacy

Article here discusses tactics used by political campaigns.
http://www.nytimes.com/2012/10/14/us/politics/campaigns-mine-personal-lives-to-get-out-vote.html

The part in question is quoted:

> The campaigns have planted software known as cookies on voters’
>   computers to see if they frequent evangelical or erotic Web sites for
>   clues to their moral perspectives. Voters who visit religious Web
>   sites might be greeted with religion-friendly messages when they
>   return to mittromney.com or barackobama.com.

How is that possible? I thought all modern browsers have same origin policy security where website A doesn't have access to any information about other website B, website C, etc.

The article makes it sound like a user browses:

```
1. presidentialcandidate.com
2. website2.com
3. website3.com
4. website4.com
5. presidentialcandidate.com
```

How can a cookie from visit #1 track user history and be revealed in visit #5?

Answer (score 6):

It's true that browsers commonly won't accept or send cookies set for a different domain than the request itself. While actual implementations vary, one straightforward technique is using *third-party cookies*. If `website2.com`, `website3.com` and `website4.com` all embed resources from `presidentialcandidate.com` -- for example, an advertisement in an iframe, or a 1x1 pixel image -- and the user's browser accepts and sends third-party cookies, then `presidentialcandidate.com` can learn, through setting and retrieving of the cookie and HTTP referer headers, that the visitor has previously visited those sites.

[RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-7.1) discusses the privacy implications of third-party cookies in greater detail.

It may not always be resources from `presidentialcandidate.com` that are enabling this process. For example, some services use *cookie syncing* to align cookie identifiers between services ([a description of cookie syncing in one scenario](http://www.adopsinsider.com/ad-exchanges/ssp-to-dsp-cookie-synching-explained/)).